# Excel File "opens up" multiple times by the same user in SharePoint 2019 using Chrome/Edge, but not when using IE

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel, 2019, chrome, edge

When opening an Excel in SharePoint using Chrome/Edge, it thinks that the user (in this case Stefan) has opened the file multiple times. It happens, when the user opens it, closes it, and reopens it etc.

[image]

However, the issue does not appear when using Internet Explorer.

Does anyone know what the problem is and/or how it can be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error message?

You could try to clear Chrome or Edge cache, then test, compare the result.